# How do I get the associated node from a webform entity?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm preprocessing a webform using hook_webform_submission_form_alter. The webform is being rendered as a node field. How can I, from inside my form_alter hook access that node?

```
function MY_MODULE_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();

    if ($parameters->has('node')) {

        // processing goes here
    }
}
```

I'm fetching it from the url parameter right now, but I would prefer to do this in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I've found out the answer.

This is how I get the webform submission, the webform object, and the associated node:

```
    function MY_MODULE_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

        $entity  = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity(); // webform submission
        $webform = $form_state->getFormObject()->getWebform(); // webform object
        $node    = $entity->getSourceEntity(); // associated node

        // (...)
    }
```